# How can I make a standard timeline?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pstricks

I am looking to make a standard timeline, nothing fancy, like the one below (although, it does not have to be like that) using any library. How can I go about the achieving this in the best way?

[image: A standard timeline]

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Here's one possibility using [`TikZ`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf):

### Update:

I made some additional improvements to the original code (older versions can be seen in the edit history of this answer):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage{tikz} 
\usetikzlibrary{chains,shapes.arrows,fit}

\definecolor{arrowcolor}{RGB}{201,216,232}% color for the arrow filling
\definecolor{circlecolor}{RGB}{79,129,189}% color for the inner circles filling
\colorlet{textcolor}{white}% color for the text inside the circles
\colorlet{bordercolor}{white}% color for the outer border of circles

\pgfdeclarelayer{background}
\pgfsetlayers{background,main}

\newcounter{task}

\newlength\taskwidth% width of the box for the task description
\newlength\taskvsep% vertical distance between the task description and arrow

\setlength\taskwidth{2.5cm}
\setlength\taskvsep{17pt}

\def\taskpos{}
\def\taskanchor{}

\newcommand\task[1]{%
  {\parbox[t]{\taskwidth}{\scriptsize\Centering#1}}}

\tikzset{
inner/.style={
  on chain,
  circle,
  inner sep=4pt,
  fill=circlecolor,
  line width=1.5pt,
  draw=bordercolor,
  text width=1.2em,
  align=center,
  text height=1.25ex,
  text depth=0ex
},
on grid
}

\newcommand\Task[2][]{%
\node[inner xsep=0pt] (c1) {\phantom{A}};
\stepcounter{task}
\ifodd\thetask\relax
  \renewcommand\taskpos{\taskvsep}\renewcommand\taskanchor{south}
\else
  \renewcommand\taskpos{-\taskvsep}\renewcommand\taskanchor{north}
\fi
\node[inner,font=\footnotesize\sffamily\color{textcolor}]    
  (c\the\numexpr\value{task}+1\relax) {#1};
\node[anchor=\taskanchor,yshift=\taskpos] 
  at (c\the\numexpr\value{task}+1\relax) {\task{#2}};
}

\newcommand\drawarrow{% the arrow is placed in the background layer 
                                                     % after the node for the tasks have been placed
\ifnum\thetask=0\relax
  \node[on chain] (c1) {}; % if no \Task command is used, the arrow will be drawn
\fi
\node[on chain] (f) {};
\begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
\node[
  inner sep=10pt,
  single arrow,
  single arrow head extend=0.8cm,
  draw=none,
  fill=arrowcolor,
  fit= (c1) (f)
] (arrow) {};
\fill[white] % the decoration at the tail of the arrow
  (arrow.before tail) -- (c1|-arrow.west) -- (arrow.after tail) -- cycle;
\end{pgfonlayer}
}

\newenvironment{timeline}[1][node distance=.75\taskwidth]
  {\par\noindent\begin{tikzpicture}[start chain,#1]}
  {\drawarrow\end{tikzpicture}\par}

\begin{document}

\begin{timeline}
\Task{Complete oral presentation\\ 27/04/2012}
\Task{Work on user interface and some modulation \\ 28/04/2012}
\Task{Work on and complete proposal to hand in \\ 29/04/2012}
\Task{Hand in proposal and astart working on Software planning \\ 04/05/2012}
\Task{Hand in Software planning and work on more content \\ 06/05/2012}
\Task{Complete full user UI with action listeners \\ 12/05/2012}
\Task{Complete beta testing and debug \\ May 13th to May 29th}
\end{timeline}

\vspace{1cm}

\definecolor{arrowcolor}{RGB}{144,168,65}
\colorlet{circlecolor}{white}
\definecolor{bordercolor}{RGB}{168,89,65}
\colorlet{textcolor}{bordercolor}
\setlength\taskwidth{1.7cm}

\begin{timeline}
\Task[M]{Grilled cheese sandwiches on whole-wheat bread, one peach}
\Task[Tu]{Penne pasta Caprese salad}
\Task[W]{Zucchini muffins with cream cheese, grapes, and watermelon}
\Task[Th]{Peanut butter and banana sandwiches, popcorn, one peach}
\Task[F]{Cream cheese and cucumber sandwich, grapes, and blueberries}
\Task[Sa]{Grilled fish with lemon, grilled corn, and whole-wheat biscuits}
\Task[Su]{Yogurth with honey and blueberries}
\end{timeline}

\end{document}
```

[image]

#### How the code works:

Inside the `timeline` environment, use `\Task{<description>}` for each task. For example:

```
\begin{timeline}
\taskmark{This is the first task}
\taskmark{This is the description of the second task and it is a little long}
\taskmark{This is the description of the third task and it is short}
\taskmark{This is the description of the fourth task}
\taskmark{This is the description of the fifth task}
\taskmark{Here is the description of the sixth task}
\end{timeline}
```

If no `\Task` command is used, only the arrow will be drawn. The optional argument for `\Task`, allows to add a label to the inner circles (if the label is too long, the width for the `inner` style will have to be increased).

Comment: I'm getting this error `"! LaTeX Error: Command \widering already defined.` What could be the issue?

Comment: @gekkostate that error indicates a conflict between names of commands. The only package that perhaps could be causing the name clash that in my code it's `fourier`; don't load it. If the error persists, it must be elsewhere in your code, not in mine. You can build a MWE illustrating the problem and add it to your question.

Comment: I removed the `fourier` package it is fixed! Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Can you please demonstrate how to add more tasks? I kind of have it figured out but it would be better if you could give an explanation of your code.

Comment: @gekkostate yes, of course, I am improving the code. As soon as I finish, I'll update it and provide an explanation.

Comment: @Gonzalo Medina great job, indeed! +1 for the code, but I wonder how can one now enter text inside the circles, e.g.,"T1", "T2", "T3", and so on?

Comment: @doctorate Thanks. Please see my updated answer.

Comment: @Gonzalo Medina, Oh really fantastic, it's more than elegant standard timeline, it is just a favorite piece of artwork that should be posted [here](http://texample.net/tikz/examples/) one day!

Comment: @GonzaloMedina, can we enter a vector of text into this code? like "Mo","Tu","We","Th","Fr","Sa".

Comment: @doctorate Will the text have a sequence (like consecutive week days, in your example) or can it be arbitrary?

Comment: @GonzaloMedina `arbitrary` as a matter of fact.

Comment: @doctorate please see the last code in my updated answer.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina, thanks a lot. it is a marvelous work.

Comment: @gekkostate and Gonzalo: it would be great if you later could clean up a bit and remove obsolete comments after the discussion. Very nice solution!

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Sure, that was my first thought when I saw it! I'll gladly add it. Btw. I think the baselines of the encircled text could be aligned in addition.

Comment: @StefanKottwitz good point; I hadn't noticed the misalignment. I'll make some improvements to the code and then I'll send it to TeXample.

Comment: @gekkostate It's not necessary to remove `fourier`. I like the font because it's a complete math font. I'm not Sherlock but I think your problem comes from `ymath`, `amsmath` is not a problem with fourier . A possibility is to load ymath and amsmath before fourier but just after loading ymath you can write something like `\let\widering\relax`. Perhaps a TeX'S expert can find something more robust.

Comment: I am trying to use this arrow in a vertical layout, but all I get is a fat horizontal arrow with this code. Is there a way to fit it in a rotated fashion?

Answer (score 16):

With PSTricks.

[image]

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\SpecialCoor
\def\Mark#1#2#3{%
    \pscircle[linewidth=2pt,linecolor=white,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=blue!75](!2.5 #1 mul 1 add 0){.5}
    \ifstrequal{#2}{t}{%
        \rput[b](!2.5 #1 mul 1 add  1){\parbox{2cm}{\scriptsize #3}}}{%
        \rput[t](!2.5 #1 mul 1 add -1){\parbox{2cm}{\scriptsize #3}}}}

\def\Axis#1{%
    \psline[linecolor=blue!50,linewidth=1.5,arrowinset=0,arrowlength=0.5]{->}(0,0)(!2.5 #1 mul 5 add 0)
    \pspolygon*[linecolor=white](0,.75)(.75,0)(0,-.75)}

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(0,-3)(10,3)
    \Axis{2}
    \Mark{0}{t}{Karl's students do not care about dashing patterns.}
    \Mark{1}{b}{Karl's students do not care about arrow tips.}
    \Mark{2}{t}{Karl's students, by the way, do not know what a transformation matrix is.}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```