# LaTeX packages for timelines

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, tikz-styles, timeline

Are there any LaTeX/TikZ packages that can create timeline as show in figures?

[image]
[image]

Comment: A search of this site for "timeline" will currently yield 334 hits.

Comment: You'll find one answer in the tags you chose for your question.

Comment: What do you find in this site? Nothing?, i can't believe. -If you remove `fill=red,` [How can I make a standard timeline?]https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/108776/124842() could help to get the second timeline.

Comment: Found couple of examples on stack including the very easy to use `chronology` but nothing so far that is closed to example #1